# getting rid of nouveau and using intel graphics

Tags: drivers, server, graphics, 15.04, nouveau

I'm running a Asus N550JK notebook, which uses an Intel HD4000-something-something Integrated GPU together with a proprietary nVidia GTX850m (known as nVidia Optimus).
I just installed Ubuntu-Server 15.04, because of the reasons listed afterwards.
(previously running Ubuntu 14.04, both as a dualboot together with Win8.1)
Now I am fighting with that stupid nouveau, which is giving me a hard time now, since it crashes my system before I can even log in...only way to get there is to boot into recovery mode and then proceed to launch the standard thingy. (but i can log in that way, so I can manipulate stuff there).

What I want to achieve with that:

1. Getting a text-based Ubuntu that can switch to Xfce if needed, but not rely on X systems. (should be the exception to use X stuff)
2. NOT using nouveau OR bumblebee OR proprietary nVidia drivers, because I want to use the Intel GPU for energy saving reasons(GPU was running pretty hot under standart ubuntu 14.04 with nouveau)
3. Using Grub to boot directly into what I have known as runlevel 3 from earlier linux-expierence.

What makes my life hard:

1. stupid nouveau driver not letting me boot correctly
2. stupid nouveau driver always (on Ubuntu Standart 14.04) using nVidia GPU therefore using a huge amount of battery (that's why i switched to ubuntu-server)
3. I can't find a thing about replacing nouveau with the Intel drivers, everyone wants to use the propretary nVidia ones...guess I'm special with this request...

What I've tried so far:

1. blacklisting nouveau in this one blacklist-file, wherever that was...
2. telling Linux to boot to runlevel 3 via GRUB
3. apt-get remove nouveau*, which in turn said that no packages matching nouveau* could be found...

Needless to say, nothing of that did anything...

I'd appreciate every help I can get!

Comment: It would be - `xserver-xorg-video-nouveau` But what you're stating about 14.04 Desktop makes no sense. By default you'd be using Intel. If nvidia-prime ect. was installed & you explicitly switched you'd be using the nvidia driver, not nouveau.  There could be a possibility when on Intel that a boot could hang on some nouveau crap, remove the above package in that case.

Answer (score 1):

There is an option to switch cards on the Nvidia settings.

This is the official instructions with the Nvidia drivers https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics

I suppose it will work on 15.04 as well. Careful to install the recommended drivers which in your case should be 346.59.
You can access the additional drivers gui from dash.

There are several posts about disabling the Nvidia card and nouveau drivers from command line but i can not recommend any, as they created problems to several users.

Example http://ubuntuguide.net/ubuntu-12-04-turn-off-discrete-graphic-card-on-boot